# how to send parameters to stored procedure using enterprise library

Tags: database, logging, parameters, enterprise-library, procedure

I have to log Exception in database, I've created pprocedure, configured Database Trace Listener, but I can't understand, how to send parameters to stored procedure in database, what esle should be configured?

Comment: nt sure i understand the question ? is it : How to pass parameters to a proc ?

Comment: maybe : EXECUTE PROC ('param1', 'param2');

Comment: it will be acceptable, if I'll call thus procedure directly with this code, but in my case procedure is called by enterprise library DatabaseFactory

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
*/        

        public int DeleteSomething(System.Guid userUUID)
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;
            try
            {
                Database db = this.GetDatabase();
                DbCommand dbc = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.uspDeleteSomething");
                dbc.CommandTimeout = 600;

                db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@UserUUID", System.Data.DbType.Guid,  userUUID );

                rowsAffected = db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbc);
            }
            finally
            { }

            return rowsAffected;
        }


        protected Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database GetDatabase()        
        {
            Database returnDb;
            returnDb = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
            return returnDb;
        }
```